# How to add .txt file to a Vue single-page application?

Tags: vue.js, txt

What is the way to add a .txt file to a Vue single-page application, so it's visible online?

For example, if I want `sitemap.txt` to appear on myvuewebsite.com at myvuewebsite.com/sitemap.txt ?

Comment: The text-file is static content, it can also be served by your web-server (Nginx, Apache HTTPD, Node Express, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

What I think you can do is to put the sitemap.txt file in your public folder  and in your router --> index.js

```
{ path: "/sitemap.txt"}
```

Answer (score 0):

After you've run npm run build, add the sitemap.txt file to the top-level of your "dist" folder, which is where your build files are.

Note: You need to add the .txt file every time you rebuild the "dist" folder, so this isn't a great solution.